# How to use the same function on different intervals of a vector in R without loops or mapply?

Tags: r, vectorization, zoo

Suppose I have a data frame such as

```
         Date    Value
1  2014-04-14   830.61
2  2014-04-11   815.69
3  2014-04-10   833.08
4  2014-04-09   872.18
5  2014-04-08   851.96
6  2014-04-07   845.04
7  2014-04-04   865.09
8  2014-04-03   888.77
9  2014-04-02   890.90
10 2014-04-01   885.52
```

Let's name it DF. And suppose I have defined min and max values of the index number.

```
minvals<-c(1,2,3)
maxvals<-c(5,7,10)
```

I want to process a function (i.e. mean value or standard deviation of Value column) for each interval. For example, take the mean of the first interval.

```
DF[minvals[1]:maxvals[1],"Value"]

         Date    Value
1  2014-04-14   830.61
2  2014-04-11   815.69
3  2014-04-10   833.08
4  2014-04-09   872.18
5  2014-04-08   851.96

mean(DF[minvals[1]:maxvals[1],"Value"])
#840.704
```

also for other minvals and maxvals. The first thing that comes to mind is mapply. But as my data has minvals and maxvals with thousands of this. Is it possible to do it in an efficient way?

p.s. In fact, it is quite similar to rolling mean but my date column include only workdays so I am not sure if rollmean function of zoo package can take care of this. Anyway suppose my time intervals are not regular also.

Comment: Have you tried an `mapply()`-based solution and found it too inefficient? "Thousands" of calls to `mean()` will typically take hardly any time at all.

Comment: `lattice::shingle` comes to mind

Comment: @baptiste -- It certainly does. Nice association there.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien Actually after changing some decisions, I had to call it 80000ish times from 400000ish. It worked pretty fast. Albeit few, past experience with mapply was not very productive.

Comment: @berkorbray, you need to accept an answer or provide feedback

Answer (score 1):

Try `data.table`

```
DFvec <- DF$Value
Ints <- data.frame(MIN = c(1,2,3), MAX = c(5,7,10))
library(data.table)
setDT(Ints)[, MEAN := mean(DFvec[MIN:MAX]), by = c("MIN", "MAX")]
Ints
##    MIN MAX     MEAN
## 1:   1   5 840.7040
## 2:   2   7 847.1733
## 3:   3  10 866.5675
```

---

Another way:

```
minvals = as.integer(minvals)
maxvals = as.integer(maxvals)
lenvals = maxvals - minvals + 1L
ix  = data.table:::vecseq(minvals, lenvals, sum(lenvals))
grp = rep(seq_along(lenvals), lenvals)

setDT(DF[ix, ])[, list(Value=mean(Value)), by=grp]
#    grp    Value
# 1:   1 840.7040
# 2:   2 847.1733
# 3:   3 866.5675
```

Comment: This doesn't look efficient (assuming `DF` is still a data.frame).

Comment: Not sure why you saying that. You can post a more efficient `data.table` solution if you like or benchmark with your first

Comment: I've benchmarked your solution agains mine. Yours was slower by a factor of 5 to 6 (probably due to the repeated data.frame subsetting).

Comment: I'm not sure if he wants to keep the data.frame or not. Why does he have a `Date` column there? I can make it with a vector easily though

Comment: @Roland I've edited it to operate on a vector, probably should have thought of it myself...

Comment: You are essentially using data.table as a looping device. I don't think this uses the whole marvelous power of that package. You could probably do much better (e.g., using rolling joins?).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the `mapply` solution. If that is too slow (give a reproducible example of you problem size), you could probably do something clever with data.table or use Rcpp.

```
x <- DF[["Value"]] #avoid data.frame subsetting in a loop
mapply(function(i1, i2) mean.default(x[i1:i2]), minvals, maxvals)
```

Benchmarks with 1e5 intervals:

```
library(microbenchmark)
set.seed(42)
i <- sample(1:3, 1e5, TRUE)
minvals<-c(1,2,3)[i]
maxvals<-c(5,7,10)[i]
microbenchmark(mapply(function(i1, i2) mean.default(x[i1:i2]), minvals, maxvals), times=10)

Unit: milliseconds
                                                             expr      min       lq   median       uq      max neval
mapply(function(i1, i2) mean.default(x[i1:i2]), minvals, maxvals) 446.0529 473.4267 489.2375 523.2335 595.5536    10
```

Comment: The bottleneck is not the interval but the length of minvals and maxvals. Thanks though :)

Comment: @berkorbay The number of intervals equals the length of `minvals` and `maxvals`, no? So, I don't understand your comment.

Comment: My bad, I misunderstood your explanation and did not read your code well. I thought you meant 1e5 intervals as the length of the intervals. After a second look at your code, yeah, your benchmark is quite true.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a several approaches.  Its not clear from the description that efficiency is really important here and readability might be more important:

```
# they all use this:
DF.Value <- DF$Value

# 1
sapply(seq_along(minvals), function(i) mean(DF.Value[minvals[i]:maxvals[i]]))

# 2
f <- function(minvals, maxvals) mean(DF.Value[minvals:maxvals])
mapply(f, minvals, maxvals)

# 3 - this one assumes that minvals equals seq_along(minvals) which is true in example
library(zoo)
w <- maxvals - minvals + 1
rollapply(DF.Value, w, mean, align = "left")[minvals]
```